# Accessing server side repeater controls in javascript validation method

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a repeater control all asp.net based.

```
    <div id="repeaterDiv">
    <asp:TextBox ID ="txtAnswer" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="4" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="isHid" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsAnswerEssential") %>' />        
    </div>
```

I am attempting to access them using Javascript so that I can perform validation on them. So I am doing it like this which is fine to some degree. I am doing it using getelementsbytagname because of the id issue with a repeater control.

```
var myTxtBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
var myHiddenField = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < myTxtBoxes.length; i++) {


    alert(myTxtBoxes[i].value);
    alert(myHiddenField[i].value);

}
```

The problem is the way Iam doing the above pulls all of the inputs in my page which means i end up with the hidden stuff like the viewstate generator by asp.net. Does anyone know of a clean way to do this. Thank you for any helpful information you provide.

Comment: Instead of using tag name, use a CSS class on the elements you'd like to refer to from JavaScript. Then use JavaScript (preferably jQuery, which makes it simple) to retrieve those elements. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: I scrape through with jquery, just. Can I assign a cssclass to an asp.net hiddenfield, do you know?

Comment: I don't think so. In any case, I doubt a HiddenField is the right thing to use in this case. You might consider some `data-` attributes on the TextBox, such as `data-essential="True"`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for anyone else.

```
<asp:Label ID="isHid" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsAnswerEssential") %>' style="display:none;" CssClass="class2" />
```

Here is the javascript ...

```
    function ValidateInput() {

        var cntrls2 = $('.class2')
        for (var i = 0; i < cntrls1.length; i++) {                
            alert(cntrls2[i].getAttribute("Value"));
        }

          }
```

It has resolved this issue I highlighted initially. Though it doesn't feel very good at all. I hope it is of use. Thank you for all your advice Mason, really appreciate you taking time out to assist me.

Comment: You should name it something more descriptive than `class2`. Also, like I mentioned earlier you should use the `data-` attributes, which will eliminate the overhead of having a dummy label. See [this for more info](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) on them. Ex: `<asp:TextBox ID ="txtAnswer" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="4" runat="server" data-essential='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsAnswerEssential") %>' />`

Answer (score 0):

I moved forward further with this thanks to mason once again. So I went with the HTML5 data essential data attribute.

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="4" runat="server"       CssClass="class1" data-essential='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
 "IsAnswerEssential") %>'  />
```

The javascript to gain access to the value is ...

```
function ValidateInput() {
        var cntrls1 = $('.class1')

        for (var i = 0; i < cntrls1.length; i++) {
            alert(cntrls1[i].getAttribute("data-essential"));                
        }
          }
```

I have to say this is really useful information which I had no knowledge about. I found this link too which might be of use to people. http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/